# vsx shortcut doesn't work

Tags: vsx

I'm now trying to add shortcut for my package. And I find [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138531.aspx)  which may be useful. As the article described, I add KeyBinding attribute in vsct file, like this:

```
<KeyBindings>
<KeyBinding guid="guidPackageTestCmdSet" id="commandId01" editor="guidVSStd97"
            key1="M" mod1="Control" >
</KeyBinding>
```

when I run this package, you can see the shortcut info "Ctrl+M" at right of the command name, but it doesn't fires after I press control + M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are creating for VS2010. Take a look at this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx). Seems like Ctrl+M is a multiple binding. Once you press Ctrl+M check for the status bar in VS and you should be able to see it waiting for another command.

Comment: thanks a lot.It worked after I changed shortcut to "Ctrl + Alt + Y" (hard to find shortcuts that are not been used in vs)

Comment: I think that document is more of a one stop shop, you can look if you want to add your own ones.

Comment: can you have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544203/issues-after-i-add-a-command-filter-to-textview